# How to mock an attribute of a class with @patch?

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I have the following class with one attribute:

```
class Eobi(): 
    def __init__(self, partitions): 
        self.partitions = partitions
```

Then I have the following test function, where I am trying to mock the attribute `partitions` of the class `Eobi`. And I have it to return 100.

```
@mock.patch('exchanges.protocols.eobi.parser.EobiExchange.partitions', return_value = 100)
def test_check_for_sequence_reset(mock_EobiExchange, xwbo_exchange, test, result):

    .....
```

The above results in some errors with regards to the patching- I have a feeling I haven't mocked the attribute correctly. Any suggestions?

The error is quite complex, so unless it is needed I will leave it out.

Here is my production code:

```
def check_for_sequence_reset(self, packet, pkthdr, partition):

        channel = self.partitions[pkthdr.partitionid].channels[packet.header.dst_ip]

        # potential sequence reset detected
        if channel.next_seqno != 0:
            if channel.next_seqno > pkthdr.applseqnum:
                if pkthdr.applseqresetindicator:
                    # Reset. No alert, this is legitimate behaviour.
                    if not partition.in_reset:
                        partition.in_reset = True
                        return True
                else:
                    partition.in_reset = False
                return False
```

I want `channel` to take the value of 100.

Comment: Why do you need to mock something you are injecting via initializer anyway?

Comment: Good question, let me add the actual code- this should shed some light